# How does the browser scale bitmap fonts?

Tags: css, web, fonts, bitmap, font-size

I am wondering if I should avoid bitmap fonts in my web pages.  Even if I specify a font size it covers, the user could zoom the page or scale the text.

So - how does the browser scale bitmap fonts?
Should I avoid them in web pages? Or does it suffice to set font-size in points to one of the explicitly supported sizes?
How can I tell if a font is a bitmap font?
How can I tell what sizes are explicitly supported for a bitmap font?

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap fonts are not used on the web, presumably because they don't scale.
(Although I don't know what the browser would do if you tried it.)

This article lists the bitmap font formats, including .FON:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_font_formats

This article lists the web font formats, including eot, woff, ttf, otf, svg:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web_fonts

None of the web font formats are bitmap formats, they are either outline or stroke.